# plesk - there's a way to setup the fqdn?

Tags: plesk, fqdn

I've a vps with plesk running, all it's working fine except for sending email.
Most of the email remain in the queue and a first look to the maillog is show that the receiver refused since the server fqdn is not correct.
I've searched around the plesk panel, but maybe I'm missing somenthing...is a parameter configurable only via console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the version of Plesk you are using! Versions **< 10** don't have an explicit settings in the panel and you have to configure it via `hostname` command. Versions **>= 10** has a handy field in the settings.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I've plesk 10.1...that setting was right under my nose!